# Clicking on notification doesn't open activity on background

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications, firebase-notifications

I send notification from the firebase, while the app run on foreground clicking on notification will work perfectly. But if the app goes on background then clicking on notification won't work. It doesn't open the **MainActivity**. Please help me where i am wrong.

**onMessageReceived()**

```
if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            //Foreground
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " +
                    remoteMessage.getNotification().toString());
            showNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle(),
                    String.valueOf(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()));
        }
else if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
           showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),
                    remoteMessage.getData().get("data"));

        }
```

**showNotification()**

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    manager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use **click_action**.

for e.g.

In your `android.manifest` file

Add the following code where you registered your activity

```
     <activity
                android:name="your activity name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="your activity name" />
                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
               </intent-filter>
   </activity>
```

Same click action you have to register in your server side.

for e.g.

```
$noti = array
    (
    'icon' => 'your_icon_name',
    'title' => 'title',
    'body' => 'msg',
    'click_action' => 'your activity name comes here'
);
```

Comment: I want to open second tab of my bottombar. I send tag id on firebase notification. How to handle that if my app is in backgroud, If user click than my app open and redirect to second tab. please can you give me some idea

Comment: @RabindraAcharya you will have to send an FCM data message instead of just a notification -> https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Answer (score 0):

Kindly use following method in FirebaseMessagingService class.

```
 @Override
    public void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {
                RemoteMessage.Builder builder = new RemoteMessage.Builder("MessageService");
                for (String key : intent.getExtras().keySet()) {
                    builder.addData(key, intent.getExtras().get(key).toString());
                }
                onMessageReceived(builder.build());
            } else {
                super.handleIntent(intent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();          
            super.handleIntent(intent);
        }
    }
```

It will be invoke app, while app is killed or in background state. Once tapped on app notification from notification tray, app will be open with the help of this method.